# Django Model Field: storing a list of tuples

Tags: database, django-models

i am trying to store x-y datasets in my DB. Basically, these datasets represent simple measurement data.

the first potential implementation would be to have a class DataPoint, storing a x-value and a y-value and a ForeignKey to a MeasurementClass.
However, i expect to have potentially thousands of measurements in the DB and each measurement has probably hundreds of data-points. I fear that such an implementation would be to slow? can a table get too large that it does not make any sense any more to store data like that?

another option i thought was to have a field which stores a list of tuples.
In that case the Measurement class would have a field holding data like:
measurement = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ...]

However, how would i implement that in Django?
I am using a MySQL database - as its free.

Please let me know your thoughts and if you have any solutions to the problem.

i did not try too much yet, except searching the internet without a reasonable answer.

ChatGPT gave the me following solution, which is however not working and i did not manage to make it work using chatGPT

```
import struct
from django.db import models

class ListTupleField(models.BinaryField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return []
        return struct.unpack(f"{len(value) // self.size:d}{self.format}", value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        return self.from_db_value(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return struct.pack(f"{len(value)}{self.format}", *value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self.value_from_object(obj)
        return str(value)

class Measurement(models.Model):
    data_points = ListTupleField(format="dd", size=16)
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

> However, I expect to have potentially thousands of measurements in the DB and each measurement has probably hundreds of data-points. I fear that such an implementation would be to slow? can a table get too large that it does not make any sense any more to store data like that?

**No**, that would be ~100'000 entries. A database uses indexes for `ForeignKey`s which makes lookups faster, it also allows us to filter effectively on X/Y-coordinates, etc. So it makes the data more usable, and it puts the database in at least [*first normal form* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Usually normals forms are specified exactly for that: to make filtering, updating and creating data effectively.

If you really want to store it in a binary format, you can alter the suggested field to:

```
import struct


class ListTupleField(models.BinaryField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return None
        n = len(value) // 8
        v = struct.unpack(n * 'd', value)
        return [v[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, n, 2)]

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        return self.from_db_value(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return struct.pack(2 * len(value) * 'd', *[xy for v in value for xy in v])
```

and use it as:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    data_points = ListTupleField()
```

Comment: thanks. i guess then, for now, i will stick to the simpler model and use the ForeignKey Method to individual datapoints.

if, at some point, i should figure that somethings not fast enough i guess i can still refactor then...

Comment: @blitzoc: some Django functionality that can often get rid of N+1 queries is `.prefetch_related`, this is a underestimated feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related